# Why is Apps Script returning an empty array for criteria values when using the getCriteriaValues() with tick boxes?

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When using the .getDataValidation() or .getDataValidations() to access the rules set on a range of tick boxes, I am running into an issue with the .getCriteriaValues() method returning a blank array.

This appears to be the case when you've set a default tick box in a cell using the menu Insert>Tick Box. By default, the values for unticked are supposed to be false and the ticked true, but when accessing the .getCriteriaValues(), the returned array is blank.

However, if you go in and set custom cell values for the tick box's data validation, then the array is returned properly, as for example ["yes","no"].

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something? How do I get a script to return the ticked and unticked values for default tick boxes?

For example, this is the script taken *directly* from developers.google.com class reference. If you set A1 as a fresh inserted tick box, this script returns a blank criteria values array:

```
function testTickboxes() {
// Log information about the data validation rule for cell A1.
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
var rule = cell.getDataValidation();
if (rule != null) {
  var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
  var args = rule.getCriteriaValues();
  Logger.log('The data validation rule is %s %s', criteria, args);
} else {
  Logger.log('The cell does not have a data validation rule.')
}
}
```

The above script example, it returns: "The data validation rule is CHECKBOX []"

If you add the line:

```
  Logger.log('The values of this cell is %s', cell.getValue());
```

It returns: "The value of this cell is false"

Why would this be?

Comment: About `Why is Apps Script returning an empty array for criteria values when using the getCriteriaValues() with tick boxes?`, I thought that this might be the current specification. For example, when the checkbox inserted as the default value (true and false) is retrieved by Sheets API, `dataValidation.condition.values` is empty. In the case of Sheets API, the default value is used as the empty value. From this situation, I thought that your situation might be the current specification. If this was not your expected answer, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

"Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?"

You are assuming that the rules that apply to checkboxes for DataValidation are the same that apply to checkboxes for everyday use.

- Under "normal" circumstances, a checkbox will return a value of 'true' or 'false' to reflect checked and unchecked values.
- when a checkbox is used with DataValidation different rules apply, the user is able to choose their own checked/unchecked values.

`requireCheckbox(checkedValue)` and `requireCheckbox(checkedValue, uncheckedValue)` enable the user to use a specificed value as the checked/unchecked value. For example, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirecheckboxcheckedvalue,-uncheckedvalue)  uses 'APPROVED' and 'PENDING'. But it could just as easily use 'Yes'/'No'. The point is that the user is able to control the checked/unchecked value *for DataValidation purposes*.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't solve my problem or question though. On the spreadsheet side, all tickboxes are data validation (at least now, if they weren't previously) and appear in the data validation sidebar. So there doesn't appear any difference between what you describe as "normal" checkboxes and data validation ones. What I'm needing are the criteriaValues of existing checkboxes on a sheet (see [dataValidation documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)). I'm not using the DataValidationBuilder to create checkboxes and set rules.